# Mini HTML document builder in Java

Tags: java, html, library

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123252/mini-html-document-builder-in-java-follow-up).)

I have this tiny library for building HTML pages in Java code:

**HtmlViewComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API for logical HTML view components, that 
 * may consist of other view components;
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public abstract class HtmlViewComponent {

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

**HtmlViewContainer.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class defines the API for HTML elements that may contain other HTML
 * elements.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public abstract class HtmlViewContainer extends HtmlViewComponent {

    protected final List<HtmlViewComponent> components = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHtmlViewComponent(HtmlViewComponent component) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "The input component is null.");
        components.add(component);
    }

    public boolean containsHtmlViewComponent(HtmlViewComponent component) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "The input component is null.");
        return components.contains(component);
    }

    public void removeHtmlViewComponent(HtmlViewComponent component) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "The input component is null.");
        components.remove(component);
    }

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

**HtmlPage.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view;

/**
 * This class is the top-level container of view components.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class HtmlPage extends HtmlViewContainer {

    private final String title;

    public HtmlPage(String title) {
        this.title = title != null ? title : "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
                                              .append("<html>\n")
                                              .append("<head>\n")
                                              .append("<title>")
                                              .append(title)
                                              .append("</title>\n")
                                              .append("</head>\n")
                                              .append("<body>\n");

        components.stream().forEach((component) -> {
            sb.append(component.toString());
        });

        return sb.append("</body>\n")
                 .append("</html>").toString();
    }
}
```

**DivComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view.support;

import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewContainer;

/**
 * This class implements a {@code div} component.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class DivComponent extends HtmlViewContainer {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<div>\n");

        components.stream().forEach((component) -> {
            sb.append(component.toString());
        });

        return sb.append("</div>\n").toString();
    }
}
```

**TableComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewComponent;

/**
 * This class represents the table component.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class TableComponent extends HtmlViewComponent {

    private final int columns;

    public TableComponent(int columns) {
        checkColumnNumber(columns);
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    private final List<List<? extends HtmlViewComponent>> table = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRow(List<HtmlViewComponent> row) {
        while (row.size() > columns) {
            row.remove(row.size() - 1);
        }

        table.add(row);
    }

    private void checkColumnNumber(int columns) {
        if (columns <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The number of columns must be a positive integer. " +
                    "Received " + columns);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<table>\n");

        for (List<? extends HtmlViewComponent> row : table) {
            sb.append("<tr>");

            for (HtmlViewComponent cell : row) {
                sb.append("<td>");
                sb.append(cell.toString());
                sb.append("</td>");
            }

            for (int i = row.size(); i < columns; ++i) {
                sb.append("<td></td>");
            }

            sb.append("</tr>\n");
        }

        return sb.append("</table>\n").toString();
    }
}
```

**TextComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view.support;

import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewComponent;

/**
 * This class represents a simple text.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class TextComponent extends HtmlViewComponent {

    private String text; 

    public TextComponent() {
        this("");
    }

    public TextComponent(String text) {
        setText(text);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text != null ? text : "";
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlPage;
import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewComponent;
import net.coderodde.html.view.support.DivComponent;
import net.coderodde.html.view.support.TableComponent;
import net.coderodde.html.view.support.TextComponent;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlPage page = new HtmlPage("FUNKEEH PAGE");

        DivComponent div1 = new DivComponent();
        DivComponent div2 = new DivComponent();

        div1.addHtmlViewComponent(new TextComponent("Hey yo!\n"));

        TableComponent table = new TableComponent(3);

        // Arrays.asList is immutable, so copy to a mutable array list.
        List<HtmlViewComponent> row1 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new TextComponent("Row 1, column 1"),
                              new TextComponent("Row 1, column 2"),
                              new TextComponent("Row 1, column 3"),
                              new TextComponent("FAIL")));



        List<HtmlViewComponent> row2 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new TextComponent("Row 2, column 1"),
                              new TextComponent("Row 2, column 2")));

        table.addRow(row1);
        table.addRow(row2);

        div2.addHtmlViewComponent(table);
        div2.addHtmlViewComponent(new TextComponent("Bye, bye!\n"));

        page.addHtmlViewComponent(div1);
        page.addHtmlViewComponent(div2);

        System.out.println(page);
    }
}
```

I don't think it is of any use, but I want to hear comments on the hierarchy aspect. Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `HtmlViewComponent` has no implementation only a method declaration, it would be more natural to use an interface instead.

In `addRow`, when there are more columns than allowed in the table, instead of mutating the input list by deleting elements, it would be better to call `subList`. It will not modify the input list and more efficient too.

You don't need to call `.toString()` in code like `sb.append(obj.toString())`, it gets called automatically.

`toString` is not really designed for display purposes. It's also strange to see `abstract String toString` declarations. Since your methods are about HTML formatting, `toHtml` would be a better name.