# Mini HTML document builder in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, html, library

(See the [previous (and first) iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123237/mini-html-document-builder-in-java).)

Now, I have incorporated all the modifications proposed by [janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos), and, thus, I have the following:

**HtmlViewComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API for logical HTML view components, that 
 * may consist of other view components;
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public interface HtmlViewComponent {

    public String toHtml();
}
```

**HtmlViewContainer.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class defines the API for HTML elements that may contain other HTML
 * elements.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public abstract class HtmlViewContainer implements HtmlViewComponent {

    protected final List<HtmlViewComponent> components = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHtmlViewComponent(HtmlViewComponent component) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "The input component is null.");
        components.add(component);
    }

    public boolean containsHtmlViewComponent(HtmlViewComponent component) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "The input component is null.");
        return components.contains(component);
    }

    public void removeHtmlViewComponent(HtmlViewComponent component) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "The input component is null.");
        components.remove(component);
    }
}
```

**HtmlPage.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view;

/**
 * This class is the top-level container of view components.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class HtmlPage extends HtmlViewContainer {

    private final String title;

    public HtmlPage(String title) {
        this.title = title != null ? title : "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toHtml() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
                                              .append("<html>\n")
                                              .append("<head>\n")
                                              .append("<title>")
                                              .append(title)
                                              .append("</title>\n")
                                              .append("</head>\n")
                                              .append("<body>\n");

        components.stream().forEach((component) -> {
            sb.append(component.toHtml());
        });

        return sb.append("</body>\n")
                 .append("</html>").toString();
    }
}
```

**DivComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view.support;

import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewContainer;

/**
 * This class implements a {@code div} component.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class DivComponent extends HtmlViewContainer {

    @Override
    public String toHtml() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<div>\n");

        components.stream().forEach((component) -> {
            sb.append(component.toHtml());
        });

        return sb.append("</div>\n").toString();
    }
}
```

**TableComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewComponent;

/**
 * This class represents the table component.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class TableComponent implements HtmlViewComponent {

    private final int columns;

    public TableComponent(int columns) {
        checkColumnNumber(columns);
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    private final List<List<? extends HtmlViewComponent>> table = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRow(List<HtmlViewComponent> row) {
        if (row.size() > columns) {
            table.add(new ArrayList<>(row.subList(0, columns)));
        } else {
            table.add(new ArrayList<>(row));
        }
    }

    private void checkColumnNumber(int columns) {
        if (columns <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The number of columns must be a positive integer. " +
                    "Received " + columns);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toHtml() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<table>\n");

        for (List<? extends HtmlViewComponent> row : table) {
            sb.append("<tr>");

            for (HtmlViewComponent cell : row) {
                sb.append("<td>");
                sb.append(cell.toHtml());
                sb.append("</td>");
            }

            // Deal with the missing table cells at the current row.
            for (int i = row.size(); i < columns; ++i) {
                sb.append("<td></td>");
            }

            sb.append("</tr>\n");
        }

        return sb.append("</table>\n").toString();
    }
}
```

**TextComponent.java**

```
package net.coderodde.html.view.support;

import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewComponent;

/**
 * This class represents a simple text.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 18, 2016)
 */
public class TextComponent implements HtmlViewComponent {

    private String text; 

    public TextComponent() {
        this("");
    }

    public TextComponent(String text) {
        setText(text);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text != null ? text : "";
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toHtml() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlPage;
import net.coderodde.html.view.HtmlViewComponent;
import net.coderodde.html.view.support.DivComponent;
import net.coderodde.html.view.support.TableComponent;
import net.coderodde.html.view.support.TextComponent;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlPage page = new HtmlPage("FUNKEEH PAGE");

        DivComponent div1 = new DivComponent();
        DivComponent div2 = new DivComponent();

        div1.addHtmlViewComponent(new TextComponent("Hey yo!\n"));

        TableComponent table = new TableComponent(3);

        // Arrays.asList is immutable, so copy to a mutable array list.
        List<HtmlViewComponent> row1 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new TextComponent("Row 1, column 1"),
                              new TextComponent("Row 1, column 2"),
                              new TextComponent("Row 1, column 3"),
                              new TextComponent("FAIL")));



        List<HtmlViewComponent> row2 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new TextComponent("Row 2, column 1"),
                              new TextComponent("Row 2, column 2")));

        table.addRow(row1);
        table.addRow(row2);

        div2.addHtmlViewComponent(table);
        div2.addHtmlViewComponent(new TextComponent("Bye, bye!\n"));

        page.addHtmlViewComponent(div1);
        page.addHtmlViewComponent(div2);

        System.out.println(page.toHtml());
    }
}
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TableComponent you have the following method :

```
public void addRow(List<HtmlViewComponent> row) {
    if (row.size() > columns) {
        table.add(new ArrayList<>(row.subList(0, columns)));
    } else {
        table.add(new ArrayList<>(row));
    }
}
```

I'd add more specialization here :

`public void addRow(TableRow row)`

and in the class Row

`public void addCell(TableCell cell)`

I'd also leave the `Component` suffix aside and use the same names as in the html terminology (Html, Div, Span, Table, TableRow, TableCell, Anchor).

Also since you the name of your review is "html document builder", why not trying the Builder pattern? Here is a glimpse to the groovy html builder : 
https://gist.github.com/kdabir/1885146

You can think also about adding support for :

- element attributes
- indentation of the html output

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<table>\n");
```

If you'll read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), you'll find a [`StringBuilder(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(java.lang.String)) method which sets the internal buffer to the specified string. Basically, it combines creating the buffer with appending the first string to it.

You could make use of it here to simplify the code to `new StringBuilder("<table>\n");`